chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android custom authentication with token not able to authenticate the user
I have first login with our server after that try to authenticate with firebase generated token to authenticate the chat sdk but it's not working.
AccountDetails details = AccountDetails.token("Your token"); ChatSDK.auth().authenticate(details).subscribe(...);
This is the code I'm using for authenticating the sdk provided by chat sdk.
https://github.com/chat-sdk/docs?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-authentication
If anyone have any idea or solution please share it.
I'm expecting when try to authenticate , I can use above mentioned code and providing firebase token it can authenticate and I can use chat sdk integration for chat.
